# Basic D3.js: using data keys?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This should be a fairly simple D3 question. I'm binding data to some circles, here is the data:

```
var linedata = [{ x:10, y:20},{x:5, y:30}];
```

And here are the circles:

```
var line = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
 }).y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
});
context.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(linedata).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("cx", line.x())
  .attr("cy", line.y())
  .attr("r", 2);
```

However, if I want to change the data and code to use some data keys, so that circles have classes attached:

```
var mydata = [{ name: 'LHR', data: [{ x:10, y:20}, {x:5, y:15} ], { name: 'SFO', data : [{x:5, y:30}, {x:4, y:8}] }];
```

I know how to edit the class attribute to use the data key, but how do I edit the cx and cy attributes?

```
context.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(mydata).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "dot " + d.name; })
  .attr("cx", line.x()) 
  .attr("cy", line.y())
  .attr("r", 2);
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { return line.x(d.data); })
```

That seems to assign the function itself to the cx attribute. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, with help from Alex's answer - I should pass the array item directly, and I shouldn't be using the `line` function at all. Instead:

```
context.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(mydata).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "dot " + d.name; })
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return x(d.data[i].x); }) 
  .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return y(d.data[i].y); }) 
  .attr("r", 2);
```

Comment: Good point. After answering, I noticed that you didn't need to use the line function at all. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

Your mydata variable is missing a `}` after the data array to close the object in the main array. Maybe that's an issue?

Also, you're passing an array when you pass `d.data`. Perhaps try passing `d.data[1]` or whatever array item you want.

Edit:: You'd probably want to use `.attr('cx', function(d, i) { return line.x(d.data[i]); }`

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the variable, so that isn't the issue. I've tried using `.attr('cx', function(d, i) { return line.x(d.data[i]); }`, but that gives the error: `Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="function g(d){return d.length<1?null:"M"+e(a(cE(this,d,b,c)),f)}"`. So I'm still confused... this seems to be assigning `cx` the function literal rather than the returned value of the function?

Comment: So this is the question: I don't understand how to get the value of the function, rather than the function itself. By default D3 seems happy with a function literal (`.attr("cx", line.x())` in the first code above), so I don't fully understand why it's unhappy with one in the second example.